# Tell C++ console to wait

Tags: c++, console

What is the method to tell the console to wait for x seconds. Is there a built in method or must I make one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's platform specific.  On Linux/UNIX, or other POSIX-compliant operating systems, you can use the [`sleep`](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl3_sleep.htm) function, which takes a parameter in seconds.  On Windows you can use [`Sleep`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686298(VS.85).aspx), which takes a parameter in milliseconds.

Comment: I get the error, 'sleep': identifier not found

Comment: Maybe you should include: #include <windows.h>

Comment: See the links to the man pages for each sleep function.  You probably need to include the appropriate headers.  On Linux, that would be `unistd.h`, on Windows you want `Windows.h` I think.  Also, please specify the OS you are using in the future, as it makes it easier for people to answer your questions succinctly.

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for the sleep method.

```
sleep(5);
```

Comment: As noted above, the sleep function is not a standard part of C++.

Answer (score 1):

If you want it to be portable, you have to use preprocessing to determine what operating system it is and include the header as appropriate.

It would be good to make a function for calling sleep, like:

```
void portableSleep(int sec) {
#   ifdef POSIX
        sleep(sec);
#   endif
#   ifdef WINDOWS
        Sleep(sec * 1000);
#   endif
}
```

Autoconf can help you with this.